# How can i get Youtube id from Firestore on Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This is the Youtube codes:

```
final YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
    initialVideoId: 'SXilnuxDRbg', // id youtube video
    flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
      autoPlay: true,
      mute: false,
    ),
  );
```

I need to get **SXilnuxDRbg** this part from Firestore. How can i make it?
Here is the Firestore: [image] Here is the what i have and what i want: [image]

Comment: Why would the initialVideoId be in Firestore? You've not shown any code that inserts it into firestore, nor does your document contain a field with said id... If the field you're looking for is "name", then all you have to do is fetch the document and get the value of the field, which @parmeet-singh 's answer instructs you how to do (more specifically it gives you `.getData()` from which you can call the field by name if I'm not mistaken `.getData().name`)

Comment: Okay, i get it, thanks

Comment: [Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=DO%20NOT%20post%20images%20of%20code%2C%20data%2C%20error%20messages%2C%20etc.)